# Generate a random password in PHP

Tags: php, random, passwords

I want to generate a random password with PHP, to later send it to a user that registers. How can I achieve this best? I already tried to work with `rand` function, but I doesn't get it working. Best would be a possibility to have a function doing that for me, so I just need to call something like

```
$pw = generatePW();
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at any tutorials, or other threads?

Comment: Are you sending the password over email?

Comment: @hRdCoder that's what I want to, yes

Comment: Ok, in terms of password security, it's generally not a good idea to send a password over email in plaintext.

Comment: Okay... well it only should be a one time password to login once and then change it (for easy mail confirmation)

Comment: Its better to send activation link via mail.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with the following function:

```
function random_string($length)
{
   $string = "";
   $chars = "abcdefghijklmanopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $size = strlen($chars);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
       $string .= $chars[rand(0, $size - 1)];
   }
   return $string; 
}
```

Here you first generate an empty string, then you define a string with all chars you want, you could also add `#` or `?` or whatever you want. After you also counted the numbers of chars you can start with filling your new string. You just use a for-loop to do this. Everytime the loopcontent is called, there is one random char (from your `$char`) added to your empty string.

You use this function (for example if you want to store your random password in a variable) by simply typing:

```
$password = rand_string(15) //the number specified in brackets is the amount of characters in your password
```

Let me know if you're experiencing any issues.

Comment: You never set `$string`. Return '' on every call, maybe meant `$string .=`?

Comment: of course, updated that, thanks for the hint

Comment: This works for my purpose, thank you. But I'll think about sending an activation link instead of a password...

Comment: Ewww. Don't use `rand()` for passwords, use [`random_int()`](https://secure.php.net/random_int) instead.